# Super expression error must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to study react native but I cant load the app
using :
`react-native 0.26.2`

This is the screenshot [image: screenshot]

In the IOS console, it has `2016-05-25 22:56:06.525 [warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:41] Sending websocketFailed with no listeners registered.
2016-05-25 22:56:06.543 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
2016-05-25 22:56:06.545 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
2016-05-25 22:56:06.562 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
2016-05-25 22:56:06.563 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.`

It can't seem to find the classes from `react-native`. I've already tried upgrading but I am still getting the error! please help! thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Platform,
  Component,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Navigator,
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
```

instead of

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import{
  AppRegistry,
  Platform,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Navigator,
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
```